# EmptyThrowable error in Android Studio's Run

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to run my App through Android Studio, but I'm receiving next error:

```
13:02:50 EmptyThrowable
     Invalid stub element type in index:
     file: file://C:/Users/d_mas/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/sources/android-25/java/util/Calendar.java
     psiElement: PsiImportList
     requiredClass: interface com.intellij.psi.PsiClass
     actualClass: class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiImportListImpl
     virtualFile: size:106178; stamp:0; modCount:1499594398217; fileType:JAVA; language:JAVA
     document: size:106178; stamp:0; committed:true; saved:true
     psiFile: size:106178; stamp:0; class:com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileImpl; language:JAVA
     stubInfo: created in getStubTree(); with backReference
     indexing info: no data
```

The Compile SDK Version is 25, Build Tools Version 25.0.3, MinSdk Version 15 and compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'. I'm using the JDK 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Invalidate caches/restart" option in the File menu.

[image]